# How can we best combine the two commands `\text` and `\color` in order to produce colored-text?

Tags: color, text

The following does what I would expect:

```latex
\color{maroon}{these words are maroon}
```

The output looks like:

[image: screen capture of LaTeX output with maroon words]

However, when I use the `\text` command, the text is not colored maroon.

```
\color{maroon}\text{these words are maroon}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `\texcolor{}{}` as in example: `\textcolor{red}{Text in red}  Text not affected` is what you want.

Comment: @Celdor - The instruction `\textcolor{red}{Text in red}` does not generate the expected output when used in math mode -- which, going by the OP's screen shot, would appear to be a relevant concern.

Comment: @mico I think you are right. `\textcolor{}{}` itself would give OP the expected output only in the text mode.

Answer (score 5):

> How can we best combine the two commands `\text` and `\color`?

The nested instructions

```
\text{\color{red}these words are red}
```

work as expected in both text mode and math mode.

Answer (score 4):

From the output, it seems you are working in Math Mode. In that case, a combination of the commands `\text{}` and `\textcolor{}{}` should suffice.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text command
\usepackage{xcolor}  % for \textcolor command

\begin{document}
    $\text{\textcolor{red}{these words are red}}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to put some curly-braces around the text to be colored.

The following works well

```latex
\color{maroon}{\text{these words are maroon}}
```

Comment: This solution does not confine the scope of `\color{red}` to the argument of `\text`.

Comment: your braces around \text are doing nothing here